# Problems importing freebase dump into Apache-Jena

Tags: freebase

I downloaded the latest data dump from freebase - it is a 22gb gzip file. However the archive only contains one file inside, which is 1.6gb.

Specifically, when I import the compressed gz file with apache-jena (tdbloader), the data is incomplete. George Clooney is missing from the database.

**EDIT:** Here's what I see when I inspect the dump:

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.  Whether the actual issue is a corrupted data file (doubtful) or a buggy Unix utility, it doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell how big the uncompressed file is using `gzip --list` because it's buggy (and documented as such on its man page).

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gzip#end

Comment: I added a screenshot to explain myself better

Comment: Ignore my answer.  It answers a question which has been edited beyond recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Like Tom Morris said,

> You can't tell how big the uncompressed file is using gzip --list because it's buggy (and documented as such on its man page). http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gzip#end

The problem is that Apache-Jena relies on the gzip information to know when to stop importing files into the DB. The freebase website recommends not unzipping the archive, however because of this bug, you actually have to, otherwise you end up with an incomplete database. I will keep this question up, because someone else might find this info useful.